# deleting data from sqlite based on date and other paramter android

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I am trying to delete some rows from table based on some conditions in particular based on dates.

I have tables containing date in string type and other fielde, here is my table structure

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_HISTORY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HISTORY + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," +  COLUMN_LOC + " TEXT," +  COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Now I want to delete all the rows based on date and COLUMN_LOC

Here is what I am doing

```
  int numDeleted = database.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_HISTORY, "date" + " < '" + writeFormat.format(d) + "'" + " AND " + DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_LOC  + " = " +location, null);
```

In above query Date is this format `Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2015` and COLUMN_LOC is string containing for example "Home", "Airport" etc

But application crashes on this delete action with error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Home (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM history WHERE date < 'Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2015' AND loc = Home
```

I do not undertands why as it contains Home fiels in row and without COLUMN_LOC paramter it works fine.

Comment: It might be because you need to put quotes around text values for sqlite queries such as ....  " = '" +location+"'"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the final SQL:

```
DELETE FROM history WHERE date < 'Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2015' AND loc = Home
```

You try to compare loc column with Home column.

Correct code will be

```
int numDeleted = database.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_HISTORY, "date" + " < '" + writeFormat.format(d) + "'" + " AND " + 
DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_LOC  + " = '" +location + "'", null);
```

**UPDATE**

For correct date comparing:

1. Table creation:

   DATABASE_CREATE_HISTORY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HISTORY + "(" +     COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," +  COLUMN_LOC + " TEXT," +  COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_DATE + " INTEGER" + ")";
2. deleting:

   int numDeleted = database.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_HISTORY, "date" + " < " + d.getTime() + " AND " + 
   DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_LOC  + " = '" +location + "'", null);

Comment: but i do not know why it is not deleting any row now....do you think the query is correct..? I suspect somethime with date

Comment: yes. SQLite doest support date data type. You store date as a string and compare it like strings. For correct comparing you should store date like INTEGER. In Java code int will be long dateValue = myDate().getTime(). I will add a code snippet in my answer

Comment: but I am stroring date as String, just applying the format here, it would be nice if you can provide snippet so that I can compare thanks

Answer (score 1):

String literals in SQL need to be quoted in `'single quotes'` and since `Home` is not quoted, it is parsed as a column name.

Consider using `?` placeholders for literals and bind values with the `selectionArgs` instead.

Also consider using a date format where the natural sort is also a chronological sort, such as unixtime or ISO 8601. `< 'Sat Mar 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2015'` will match rows with an alphabetically smaller-than value for the date.